# Should one learn the commentary of a Kohen first, before a Yisrael's and there's an obligation of V'kidashto?

Tags: kohen-priest

If one is learning Shulchan Aruch for example, Should one learn the Sha"ch before the Ta"z since he's a Kohen and there's an obligation of V'kidashto or does that obligation only apply to an instance when there's a physical kohen present and then allowing him to speak or take a portion first would be the mitzvah of V'kidashto? please source your answer.

Comment: Your answer should probably be here since this is a more direct question

Comment: @sam - The site does not allow it once it's closed.

Comment: I meant one of the administrators should do it